# How to print a random number with random method in constructor? [JAVA]

Tags: java, random, numbers

I want to use a method called printOneRandom to print a random number, but I am only allowed to create one single instance of Random in the constructor. (I need to create a similar method which uses Random again later) My code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumberHandler
{

public RandomNumberHandler()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
}

public void printOneRandom(Random rand) {
    Random random = rand;
    System.out.println(random);

    }
}
```

I get no output. Thanks

Comment: have you even bothered looking for `Random` its functions? See the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the `Random` as a **field**, and use that `Random` to call `nextInt` (you don't **print** the `Random`). Like,

```
public class RandomNumberHandler {
    private Random rand;

    public RandomNumberHandler() {
        rand = new Random();
    }

    public void printOneRandom() {
        System.out.println(rand.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Which you could write even *simpler*, like

```
public class RandomNumberHandler {
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public void printOneRandom() {
        System.out.println(rand.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Both are equivalent. The second example gets a default constructor. That default constructor is isomorphic (at the bytecode level) with the first example in this case.